# VB.net program with no UI

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, vbc

I'm making a VB.net program via a text file and I'm compiling it using vbc.exe via command line.  I'm trying to get just a simple program to run in the background of my computer.  Problem is, it displays the annoying console window.  How do I get nothing to show?  No form, no console?

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, kind of, I really don't need it to be one.  It's just a small light weight program for personal use.  Nothing that needs to be installed as a service.  I would also run it myself.

Comment: But if there's no Form and no Console, how would you interact with it?  Close it?  Do something with it?  I think we need context here for what the program does.

Comment: @LarsTech The program itself is handled through key presses.  It uses key hooks to read what I press and based on what keys I press (e.g. SHIFT + TAB) to do something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need a form of some kind to keep the message loop going.

Maybe a [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) type program.  It would keep it away from the task bar and desktop areas.

And then customize the NotifyIcon to "Only Show Notifications" from the "Customize" menu for your icon using Windows.

Comment: Lars is correct - if you don't want to use a windows service then you shouldn't be running a program in the background without the user being able to 'see it' - this will also give them the option to Exit the application without having to resort to task manager.

Answer (score 9):

Just use windows forms application don't load the form at all! Just go in project properties and uncheck enable application framework. Now, in the startup object dropdown, select "sub main". Add a module to the project and put a `Public Sub Main()` in it. You do all the stuff in `main()` and don't load form at all.

Answer (score 5):

1) Add a module in your project, and create Sub Main
2) Write whatever you want in Sub Main,and MAKE SURE you end it with this statement:

```
Application.Run()
```

3) Open properties of your project and choose "Sub Main" as startup object

So , your application will have NO INTERFACE (NO FORM / NOT CONSOLE APPLICATION) and will run from  Sub Main(), in addition it will NOT TERMINATE once all the code in Sub Main has executed.Your program will run like a NORMAL windows form application, and will only exit when you want.

Comment: (Hmm... Some people downvote another's answers and upvote themselves...)

Comment: It worked!, i've just created a system.timers.timer() in Sub Main and started it... finally just called Application.Run(), and it behaves as a service. Using a while True bucle consumed 25% of CPU. Thank you!

Comment: @ZeroWorks While-true is a bad practice. Use Sleep() function instead. And feel free to upvote if it helped ;)

Comment: yes while-true consumed 25% of CPU and I used another approach, also I upvoted but it seems somebody downvoted this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I upvoted both MemoryVandal and Jet answers because in this one you didn't tell about "uncheck enable application framework". Thanks to both for the answers, it helps me a lot.