# Call function on Main Module

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have a VB.NET script that creates mail accounts using smartermail webservice, i know nothing of VB.Net but i have a little knowledge of programming. I created a new project on Visual Studio 2012 and know i need to call the function that creates the accounts on the main module to run it, that's a console app project.

Main Module (Module1.vb) is as follows:

```
Module Module1
      Sub Main()
      End Sub 
End Module*
```

My function is:

```
 Sub fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()
```

It's on the file **cria_contas_lote.vb** in the same directory.

Content of cria_contas_lote.vb:

```
Sub fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()

    Dim oPainelWS As PainelControle.svcSmarterMail
    Dim sRetorno As String = ""

    Try
        'oPainelWS = New PainelControle.svcSmarterMail("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Erro ao efetuar a conexão no servidor remoto: " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim sNomeArquivo As String = "C:\dir\emails.xlsx"
    Dim sSQL As String = ""

    Dim stringExcel As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sNomeArquivo & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
    Dim oExcel As New OleDbConnection(stringExcel)

    Try
        oExcel.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("O arquivo não foi localizado ou ocorreu um erro de abertura no servidor. Arquivo: " & sNomeArquivo)
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & "================================================")
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & "================================================")

        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim oDataSet As New DataSet
    Try
        Dim oExcelAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [contas_pop$]", oExcel)
        oExcelAdapter.Fill(oDataSet, "conteudo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("A tabela CONTAS_POP não foi localizada. Renomeie sua WorkSheet para CONTAS_POP")
        oExcel.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    oExcel.Close()

    Dim oDataview As DataView = oDataSet.Tables("conteudo").DefaultView

    Dim lTotal As Long = 0
    Dim lErro As Long = 0
    Dim oLinha As DataRow
    Dim iTamanhoCaixa As Integer = 1024
    Dim sComCopia As String

    For Each oLinha In oDataSet.Tables("conteudo").Rows

        If Not (Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString) = "") Then

            Console.Write("Criando [" & Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString) & "]...")
            sRetorno = ""
            sComCopia = Trim(oLinha("enviar_copia").ToString)
            iTamanhoCaixa = oLinha("tamanho_mb")

            sRetorno = CriaContaPOP(Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString), Trim(oLinha("apelidos").ToString), Trim(oLinha("password").ToString), iTamanhoCaixa, oLinha("nome").ToString, sComCopia, "admin", "password")
            'sRetorno = oPainelWS.CriaContaPOP(oLinha("conta"), Trim(oLinha("apelidos").ToString), oLinha("senha"), iTamanhoCaixa, "", sComCopia, "", "")
            Console.WriteLine("Retorno: " & sRetorno)
            'If Not (sRetorno = "OK") Then
            'Exit Sub
            'End If

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        End If

    Next


End Sub


Public Function CriaContaPOP(ByVal sConta As String, ByVal sApelidos As String, ByVal sSenha As String, ByVal iTamanhoCaixaKB As String, ByVal sNome As String, ByVal sForwardTo As String, ByVal sAdminUsuario As String, ByVal sAdminSenha As String) As String


    If Not (iTamanhoCaixaKB > 1) Then
        Return "ERRO: Tamanho da caixa postal não pode ser inferior a 1 KB"
    End If

    Dim aContaNome As String() = Split(sConta, "@")
    Dim sContaNome As String = ""
    Dim sDominio As String = ""
    sContaNome = aContaNome(0)
    sDominio = aContaNome(1)

    Dim oUsuarios As New svcUserAdmin
    Dim oUsuarioInfo As New SettingsRequestResult
    Dim oResultado As New GenericResult

    oResultado = oUsuarios.AddUser2(sAdminUsuario, sAdminSenha, sContaNome, sSenha, sDominio, sNome, "", False, iTamanhoCaixaKB)
    If (oResultado.Result = False) Then
        Return "ERRO: Não foi possivel incluir a conta de e-mail: " & oResultado.Message
    End If


    If Not (sForwardTo.ToString = "") Then
        Dim arrInfo(0) As String
        arrInfo(0) = "forwardaddress=" & sForwardTo.ToString
        oResultado = oUsuarios.SetRequestedUserSettings(sAdminUsuario, sAdminSenha, sConta, arrInfo)
        If (oResultado.Result = False) Then
            Return "ERRO: Não foi possivel incluir a conta de e-mail: " & oResultado.Message
        End If
    End If

    Return "OK"

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? Because as it stands it sounds like all you need to do is

```
Module Module1 

    Sub Main() 
        fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()
    End Sub 

    Sub fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()
        ' Do something.
    End Sub

End Module
```

If "fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote" is a class then you might have to do something like:

```
Module Module1 

    Sub Main() 
        dim email as new cria_contas_lote()

        email.fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()
    End Sub 

End Module
```

Without seeing the cria_contas_lote file its hard to know.

Edit: Below is how you can call it all from just the module

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()

End Sub

Sub fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote()

    Dim oPainelWS As PainelControle.svcSmarterMail
    Dim sRetorno As String = ""

    Try
        'oPainelWS = New PainelControle.svcSmarterMail("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Erro ao efetuar a conexão no servidor remoto: " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim sNomeArquivo As String = "C:\dir\emails.xlsx"
    Dim sSQL As String = ""

    Dim stringExcel As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sNomeArquivo & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
    Dim oExcel As New OleDbConnection(stringExcel)

    Try
        oExcel.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("O arquivo não foi localizado ou ocorreu um erro de abertura no servidor. Arquivo: " & sNomeArquivo)
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & "================================================")
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Console.Write(vbCrLf & "================================================")

        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim oDataSet As New DataSet
    Try
        Dim oExcelAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [contas_pop$]", oExcel)
        oExcelAdapter.Fill(oDataSet, "conteudo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("A tabela CONTAS_POP não foi localizada. Renomeie sua WorkSheet para CONTAS_POP")
        oExcel.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    oExcel.Close()

    Dim oDataview As DataView = oDataSet.Tables("conteudo").DefaultView

    Dim lTotal As Long = 0
    Dim lErro As Long = 0
    Dim oLinha As DataRow
    Dim iTamanhoCaixa As Integer = 1024
    Dim sComCopia As String

    For Each oLinha In oDataSet.Tables("conteudo").Rows

        If Not (Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString) = "") Then

            Console.Write("Criando [" & Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString) & "]...")
            sRetorno = ""
            sComCopia = Trim(oLinha("enviar_copia").ToString)
            iTamanhoCaixa = oLinha("tamanho_mb")

            sRetorno = CriaContaPOP(Trim(oLinha("conta").ToString), Trim(oLinha("apelidos").ToString), Trim(oLinha("password").ToString), iTamanhoCaixa, oLinha("nome").ToString, sComCopia, "admin", "password")
            'sRetorno = oPainelWS.CriaContaPOP(oLinha("conta"), Trim(oLinha("apelidos").ToString), oLinha("senha"), iTamanhoCaixa, "", sComCopia, "", "")
            Console.WriteLine("Retorno: " & sRetorno)
            'If Not (sRetorno = "OK") Then
            'Exit Sub
            'End If

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        End If

    Next


End Sub

Public Function CriaContaPOP(ByVal sConta As String, ByVal sApelidos As String, ByVal sSenha As String, ByVal iTamanhoCaixaKB As String, ByVal sNome As String, ByVal sForwardTo As String, ByVal sAdminUsuario As String, ByVal sAdminSenha As String) As String


    If Not (iTamanhoCaixaKB > 1) Then
        Return "ERRO: Tamanho da caixa postal não pode ser inferior a 1 KB"
    End If

    Dim aContaNome As String() = Split(sConta, "@")
    Dim sContaNome As String = ""
    Dim sDominio As String = ""
    sContaNome = aContaNome(0)
    sDominio = aContaNome(1)

    Dim oUsuarios As New svcUserAdmin
    Dim oUsuarioInfo As New SettingsRequestResult
    Dim oResultado As New GenericResult

    oResultado = oUsuarios.AddUser2(sAdminUsuario, sAdminSenha, sContaNome, sSenha, sDominio, sNome, "", False, iTamanhoCaixaKB)
    If (oResultado.Result = False) Then
        Return "ERRO: Não foi possivel incluir a conta de e-mail: " & oResultado.Message
    End If


    If Not (sForwardTo.ToString = "") Then
        Dim arrInfo(0) As String
        arrInfo(0) = "forwardaddress=" & sForwardTo.ToString
        oResultado = oUsuarios.SetRequestedUserSettings(sAdminUsuario, sAdminSenha, sConta, arrInfo)
        If (oResultado.Result = False) Then
            Return "ERRO: Não foi possivel incluir a conta de e-mail: " & oResultado.Message
        End If
    End If

    Return "OK"

End Function

End Module
```

Your issue is your missing the following types:

- PainelControle.svcSmarterMail
- svcUserAdmin
- SettingsRequestResult
- GenericResult

These are not built in .Net types and must be defined in either another file.  Once you've found the missing classes just add them into the project and you should be good to go.

Comment: I want to know how to reference the file cria_contas_lote.vb so the Main Module knows where to find the function fnc_CriaContas_Email_Lote.

Basically all i want is to make Main Module run the entire function.

Comment: Do you mean add it in to your project?  Can you past the contents of cria_contas_lote file into the question?

Comment: I have been added to the question

Comment: Great, thanks alot! The remaining itens i can deal with i think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make Sub Main run ENTIRE function, and DON'T EXIT as sub main is executed.
I have written answer of your question here : [VB.net program with no UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168304/vb-net-program-with-no-ui/17907335#17907335)

```
Sub Main()
    'Write whatever you want, and add this code at the END:
    Application.Run
End Sub
```